# Spring 4.1 MVC not dispatch my Ajax Json call to my controller method, 404 Not Found error occur

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

I had a Spring MVC application runs on Spring framework 3.2, and now, I am move it to Spring MVC 4.1. Everything is fine except jQuery 1.7.2 Ajax/Json call get "404 Not Found" error page.

Config as: web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <description>generated-persistence-filter</description>
    <filter-name>postgresql41Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>postgresql41</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <description>generated-sitemesh-filter</description>
    <filter-name>Sitemesh Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
```

web-context.xml as:

```
<bean id="beanNameViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
</bean>

<bean id="iPhoneUserAgentViewResolver" class="org.skyway.spring.util.viewresolution.UserAgentViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="agentSubstring" value="iPhone" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/iphone/" />
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
```

Controller class as:

```
@Controller("FirmController")
@ResponseBody
public class FirmController {
/*Added by CheckABNfromABR*/
@RequestMapping(value="/checkAbnbyAbr", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String checkAbnbyAbr(@RequestParam("abn") String abn, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale, Model model) throws IOException{
    /*ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();*/
    /*AbnInfo requesInfo = mapper.readValue(json, AbnInfo.class);*/
    AbnInfo abnInfo = new AbnInfo();
    abnInfo.setAbn(abn);

    String viewName = "Success";
    if (viewName.equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
        abnInfo.setValidation("Success");
    else
        abnInfo.setValidation("Error");
    return toJson(abnInfo);
}
}
```

javascript code as:

```
function checkAjaxCall(inabn){
/*var name = $('#name').val(); 
var location = $('#location').val(); */
/*var json = {"name" : name,"location" : location};  */
/*var json = {"abn" : inabn};*/
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "checkAbnbyAbr",
    type: 'GET',
    data: "abn="+inabn,
    dataType: "json",
    /*cache:    false,*/
    async:  false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    },
    success:function(response){
        /*alert("Validation: "+response.validation+"   Name: "+response.name+"  Location: "+response.location);*/
        console.log("Validation: "+response.validation+"|");
    },
    error:function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
return true;
};
```

request headers in firebug:

```
Accept  application/json
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type    application/json
Cookie  JSESSIONID=55AD33FFBF4524926A53C660FA734F01
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/OZSSCMEMAC/newFirm
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

response Headers in firebug:

Content-Language en
   Content-Length   1042
   Content-Type text/html;charset=utf-8
   Date Tue, 04 Nov 2014 00:14:43 GMT
   Server   Apache-Coyote/1.1

I set log4j.properties to support spring application on debug status, I got some server information as:

```
2014-11-04 10:14:43,524 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-34] OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
2014-11-04 10:14:43,524 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-34] OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
2014-11-04 10:14:43,524 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-34] OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
2014-11-04 10:14:43,524 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-34] OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
2014-11-04 10:14:43,524 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-34] EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
2014-11-04 10:14:43,524 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-34] EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Seems the Ajax/Json request was handled by OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter and the handler didn't found the right Controller methods.

I believe there are some configure missed in the configure files, I don't found any thing from google for Spring 4.1 Ajax/Json call configuration.

Any one has this experience, please advise!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your Dispatcher Servlet which is what maps requests to contollers. It is defined in your web.xml like this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/action-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In your action-servlet.xml you'll need to specify:

```
  <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="your.package"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your point out right direction. Actually, spring 4.1 is quite different with Spring 3.1. I have to explicitly specify we every request mapping in web.xml servlet-mapping such as add: